# how to send a var type from qml to python slot

Tags: c++, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, qml

I need to send a list of integers from qml to python class slot . I created a list in qml as the following

```
 property var checkBoxStatus: [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

in a button click i called a slot of my python class with the list as argument

```
dataManager.applyFilterOptions(checkBoxStatus)
```

my slot in datamanager class is

```
@pyqtSlot(list)
    def applyFilterOptions(self,filterOption):
        print(filterOption)
```

but I am getting an error like

> TypeError: unable to convert a QVariant back to a Python object

what is the compitable data type for variant data type in qml. Thanks in advance.

Comment: variant (QVariant) is not a type, this error means that your slot argument type/s is not matching what is sent from QML

Comment: I updated my slot as                                                                                             @pyqtSlot(int,int,'QStringList')
    def applyFilterOptions(self,filterOption=[],*args):
        print(filterOption)                                                                                          But I am getting only a String list .I need an Integer List

Comment: What version of PyQt are you using? In PyQt5 5.10 it works correctly, try changing `list` to `object`